# How can I create an instance of a class used for data management in a Xamarin application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is the way I am doing it now:

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static DataManager db;

    public App()
    {
        DB.appUpdated = "Feb 1, 2017";
        DB.appVersion = "0.1";
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = ..
    }

    public static DataManager DB
    {
        get
        {
            if (db == null)
            {
                db = new DataManager();
            }
            return db;
        }
    }


    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        App.DB.InitData();
    }
}
```

What I would like to know is are there better ways to start up a singleton instance of a class in a Xamarin application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answer

As your app grows, if you keep adding static properties to the `App` class, `App` will become very cluttered and unmanageable.

I recommend implementing the Singleton pattern directly in the `DataManager` class.

## Implement Singleton Pattern in DataManager.cs

```cs
public class DataManager
{
    static readonly Lazy<DataManager> _instanceHolder = 
                new Lazy<DataManager>(() => new DataManager());

    ...

    //private constructor to prevent multiple instances of DataManager
    private DataManager()
    {
        ...
    }

    public static DataManager Instance => _instanceHolder.Value;

    ...
}

public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        DataManager.Instance.appUpdated = "Feb 1, 2017";
        DataManager.Instance.appVersion = "0.1";
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = ..
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        DataManager.Instance.InitData();
    }
}
```

## Sample App

I've implemented this Singleton Pattern in this sample Xamarin.Forms app:
https://github.com/brminnick/XamConverter

For example, this class uses the Singleton pattern:
https://github.com/brminnick/XamConverter/blob/master/Source/XamConverter/Models/UnitsOfMeasurement/Celsius.cs

And this ViewModel utilizes the Singleton:
https://github.com/brminnick/XamConverter/blob/master/Source/XamConverter/ViewModels/ConversionViewModel.cs